Vue.js - How to read external properties file and serve into components
I have a Vue.js application and I would like to know how to read and use the external properties file. Then I need to use this properties inside the components.
I would also like to know if is it possible in Vue.js to use service files as per Angular and call them inside the components. I think I need to use the service because it should be used by all components.
For Example: I have Vue.js component and inside it I need to retrieve a property from the external file. I would like to call the service function for getting the property by passing its name.
I want to specify that I cannot use .env or any of its variations like .env.production for this.

Do you mean .properties file? How is it related to the project? "I cannot use .env" - why? This may be specific to how you build the app and the tools you use, this was omitted

Yes I am using a .properties file. This file is different depending on the environment in which the application is deployed (local or test) and so the app.js and app.js.map files are different. This vue.js application is part of a larger application that is based on jsf and based on maven profiles it calls certain microservice's urls, the .properties file must be used to choose the urls to call.

Again, this depends on how you build the app, no specific recommendations can be given. Please, update the question. You could parse it on build with something like https://github.com/gagle/node-properties and provide to the app somehow. Or fetch it and parse on client side, but it shouldn't contain sensitive data, of course. As for a service, it's basically ES module, unless it can be proven that a more complex approach is required like in Angular (which is often considered overengineered for that matter)
